# Check if all substrings of list are in a string

Tags: python, string, if-statement, substring

Assuming I have a list of strings:

```
Dates_list = [DD_MM_YYYY, DD_MM_YYYY, DD_MM_YYYY, ...]
```

Where DD is a day, MM is a month and YYYY is a year.

I want a pythonic way to generate a new list extracting all elements of `Dates_list` where `DD = 01` and `MM = 06` and `YYYY=1950`.

The following command

`new_list= [f for f in Dates_list  if (x in for x in [DD,MM, YYYY ])]`

returns all elements for which one of the three condition is satisfied (it's basically an `or` ).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want `[f for f in Dates_list if f == '01_06_1950']`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dates_list = ["01_06_1950", "DD_MM_YYYY", "DD_MM_YYYY"]
print(list(filter(lambda x: x.split("_")[0] == "01" or x.split("_")[1] == "06" or x.split("_")[2] == "1950",Dates_list)))
```

you can get the expected result using above code. `filter` use to filter the dates only match given conditions. In the code each date string split using `"_"` and compare with condition values. For that use `split`.